# PHP Add button to view all the contents of entire record MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

Currently I have a query running that brings up all the contents of the 'products' table and the 'user' associated with the products. It prints on a table. I want to create a button, that brings up the entire records.
Please note that I must only be able to view the selected record only.. How would I go about this?

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>user_id</th>
<th>user_name</th>
<th>selected_product</th>
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))


  echo "<td>" . $row['user_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['user_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['selected_product'] . "</td>";
```

So a button should appear for each record that is returned as a result. When I click this button another window should appear which shows the entire contents  (for this record only) and the user associated.
How does the button know which record its associated with.

Comment: link to the page like `page.php?user_id=$row['user_id']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="anotherpage.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id']?>" ><button>View Details</button></a>
```

This will take you to another page.
Use get method tho get the id into php variable.

```
$userId = $_GET['id'];
```

And now use sql query to fetch all the data from the database for single user.

```
$userResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE user_id = ".$userId);
```

Comment: <a href="anotherpage.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id']?>" ><button>View Details</button></a>                    There seems to be an error with the first line

Comment: it doesnt show an error message as such but there is an error there. i think its something to do with the speech marks"" as html and php are being used. Any ideas?

Comment: okay.. try this..

echo '<td><a href="anotherpage.php?id='.$row['user_id'].'</td>';

Comment: That code has no errors but isnt showing a button... I'm currently using ";
  echo "<td>" . $row['a field'] . "</td>";      to echo fields from the table

Comment: echo '<td><a href="anotherpage.php?id='.$row['user_id'].'"><button>View Details</button></td>';

Comment: Hi for some reason the WHERE statement doesnt execute, im not sure if the id is being passed through

Comment: when the next page is opened, are you getting the id in the URL?