# PHP JavaScript: PopUp Window

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I have a table which echos a button, currently this button takes you to the 'details.php' with £booking_id record taken over to the new php scrpit.
Here is my current code:

```
echo '<td>a href="Details.php?id='.$row['booking_id'].'"><button>View Details</button></td>';
```

I would like this button to open a new popup window. How do i merge the two together, so when i click the button the popup window and takes the 'booking_id' record over.  i have the java script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('Details.php);">View Details</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<td>';
echo '<input type="button" value="View Details" onclick="JavaScript:newPopup(\'Details.php?id='.$row['booking_id'].'\')" />';
echo '</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<html>
<head><title>No Head</title></head>
<body>    
<?php    
$rows = array(
    0 => array('booking_id' => 1),
    1 => array('booking_id' => 2),
    2 => array('booking_id' => 3),
    3 => array('booking_id' => 4),
);    
echo '<table>';
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    echo "\n<tr><td>";
    echo '<a href="Details.php?id=' . $row['booking_id'] .'"';
    echo ' onclick="javascript:popup(this.href); return false;">';
    echo 'View Details';
    echo '</a>';
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "\n</table>";
?>    
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open( url, 'popUpWindow',
        "height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes"
    )
}
</script>
</html>
```

**DETAILS.PHP**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Details for ID <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You havent included the button, also the size of the window needs to be what i specify

Comment: The script itself is returning errors, how would iput this together with the script, so that with each record that is echo out. it shows the button and when the button is preessed the popup window is shown

Comment: What you accepted as correct was my initial answer. Also my answer provides a full example. Found out that this also solves your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616851/php-add-button-to-view-all-the-contents-of-entire-record-mysql :)